# HTML5 canvas: only outer shadow

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

If I draw a rectangle to the canvas, and I enable the shadows, then there will be created inner, and outer shadows too, but I only want outer shadow.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
ctx.shadowBlur = 5;

ctx.strokeRect(20,30,150,75);
```

The only way I've found is `ctx.clearRect(20,30,150,75);`. But it's not really what I want, because there  may be something under my rect, and I don't want to delete it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Maybe [this help](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-shadow-offset-tutorial/) `context.shadowOffsetX` and `context.shadowOffsetY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fetch the pixels inside the rectangle, do the painting and put those pixels back. That way, pixels inside the rectangle won't change: http://jsfiddle.net/dkAKE/.

```
var imgdata = ctx.getImageData(20, 30, 150, 75);
ctx.strokeRect(20, 30, 150, 75);
ctx.putImageData(imgdata, 20, 30);
```

To retain the border, use `(21, 31, 148, 73)` as the area (assuming a stroke width of 1px).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.fillRect()` instead of `.strokeRect()`. This will create a solid rectangle that has an inner color you define as `.fillStyle()`

```
ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
ctx.fillRect(20,30,150,75);
```

You will still have the problem of it overwriting whatever was underneath the rectangle, so you would still need pimvdb's solution to solve that problem.